# How to line-break from css, without using <br />?

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

How to achieve same output without `<br>`?

```html
<p>hello <br> How are you </p>
```

**output:**

```
hello
How are you
```

Answer (score 472, accepted):

Impossible with the same HTML structure, you must have something to distinguish between `Hello` and `How are you`.

I suggest using `span`s that you will then display as blocks (just like a `<div>` actually).

```css
p span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p><span>hello</span><span>How are you</span></p>
```

Comment: note also how much additional mark-up there is - the `<br />` element exists for a very good reason. If you want the line break because they are separate paragraphs, then simply mark them up as separate paragraphs.

Comment: You might need structured lines without actually using paragraphs. To markup a poem, a song or an address for example

Comment: @VincentRobert Right, but a poem is the canonical example for when `<br>` is the correct markup. Spans for a poem would be “wrong.”

Comment: Note that assigning display: block to an element will force a line break before and after, and so is not at all the same as having one line break.

Comment: Definitely use the <p> elements. A <span> element should NOT be made into display:block, the whole point of <span> is that it's inline. I would do it this way: <div><p>hello</p><p>How are you</p></div>. No wonked out CSS required.

Comment: "No wonked out CSS required" You may still need to check line-height

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to add a second line subtext to BS4 and this is solution; except use `<span>` instead of `<p>` and set the second span to a smaller font size. Thx so much!

Comment: or just <p>hello<span></span>How are your</p>

Answer (score 518):

You can use [`white-space: pre;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to make elements act like `<pre>`, which preserves newlines.  Example:

```css
p {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<p>hello 
How are you</p>
```

Comment: often better than `pre` is `pre-line`, which allows wrapping.

Comment: More on differences between pre-line and pre-wrap at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: I preferred pre in my case, because I can also use text-overflow

Comment: Note that this won't work with react because the text is eventually bundled and will be put on the same line, which won't trigger `white-space` CSS rule.

Comment: If you want it work with react, wrap the text in a template string when rendering.

Answer (score 158):

#### Use `<br/>` as normal, but hide it with `display: none`

I would expect most people finding this question are looking to use responsive design to decide whether or not a line-break appears in a specific place.

While not immediately obvious, you can apply `display:none` to a `<br/>` in order to hide it.

```
br { display: none; }
```

This means you can use media queries just as you would for any other css.

```html
<div>
  The quick brown fox<br />
  jumps over the lazy dog
</div>
```

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 20em) {
  br {
    /* hide the BR tag for wider screens (i.e. no line break) */
    display: none; 
  }
}
```

This can be useful if you need to force a line break in a different place based on the screen width. And of course you can also use `&nbsp;` if you want to always prevent a line break from happening in a specific place.

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/nNbD3/1/)

Comment: Simon, you are spot on — the example you name is the exact reason I was researching this question and the `display: none` solution is by far the most appropriate and useful.

Comment: Note that for cases where it would cause words to run together, you could use something like `display: inline-block; width: 1em;` instead of `none`.

Comment: You could even apply a class to the `<br class='foo'>` if you needed more control but don't go too crazy!

Comment: Another "why didn't I think of this?!" answer. `<br/>` is great at what it does; no need to reinvent the wheel. Thanks!

Comment: Similar concept can be applied to flex-box layout : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732575/line-break-in-multi-line-flexbox/50978270#50978270

Comment: Although an interesting answer, the questioner was looking to do it without <br> i.e. respecting line breaks in the HTML, which is tackled by some other answers with pre-line and pre-wrap CSS.

Comment: @amh15 he doesn’t say WHY he wants to do that. Or rather what is wrong with BR. Is it preformatted text from a weather report web service, or is it a responsive design question. At time of answering all the pre/word wrap answers were already there. You’re right that the details matter but my answer has helped a lot of people that found this question based on keywords so I don’t see why you have to be so nit picky. I’d love to know what he really wanted to do. But I also don’t care.

Comment: The Tailwind CSS syntax is `<br class="hidden sm:block" />` in case you need it.

Answer (score 147):

There are several options for defining the handling of white spaces and line breaks.
If one can put the content in e.g. a `<p>` tag it is pretty easy to get whatever one wants.

For preserving line breaks but not white spaces use `pre-line` (not `pre`) like in:

```
<style>
 p {
     white-space: pre-line; /* collapse WS, preserve LB */
   }
</style>

<p>hello
How are you</p>
```

If another behavior is wanted choose among one of these (WS=WhiteSpace, LB=LineBreak):

```
white-space: normal;   /* collapse WS, wrap as necessary, collapse LB */
white-space: nowrap;   /* collapse WS, no wrapping,       collapse LB */
white-space: pre;      /* preserve WS, no wrapping,       preserve LB */
white-space: pre-wrap; /* preserve WS, wrap as necessary, preserve LB */
white-space: inherit;  /* all as parent element */
```

[SOURCE: W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

Answer (score 72):

The **"\a"** command in CSS generates a carriage return. This is CSS, not HTML, so it shall be closer to what you want: *no extra markup*.

In a `blockquote`, the example below displays both the title and the source link and separate the two with a carriage return (`"\a"`):

```css
blockquote[title][cite]:after {
  content:attr(title)"\a"attr(cite)
}
```

Comment: Fancy, but totally unneeded for what the question was.

Comment: +1 because its CSS only, and doesn’t recommend use of pre, br tags nor changing the display mode to block (which adds different behavior, might break if the parent is in `display:flex` and therefore is a hack in this context). Its not fancy, really, just a modern technique. If you want the exact same markup, but to actually react differently that’s the way to go.

Comment: Brilliant idea. Note the `"` – do not use simple quotes `'` because you want to allow the `\a` to get parsed as a special character.

Comment: i want to give +1 but it not work for me on chrome 55

Comment: I would have up-voted this if there was some HTML and maybe a Fiddle to help visualize what you're doing.

Answer (score 43):

In the CSS use the code

```css
p {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

With this CSS every enter inside the `P` tag will be a break-line at the HTML.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Works perfectly for element content generated from JS (e.g. JSON result from AJAX query, angular-schema-form, etc.) that gets passed through escaping/sanitization (e.g. normal AngularJS escaping behavior when not using ngBindHtml)

Answer (score 31):

Building on what has been said before, this is a pure CSS solution that works.

```
<style>
  span {
    display: inline;
  }
  span:before {
    content: "\a ";
    white-space: pre;
  }
</style>
<p>
  First line of text. <span>Next line.</span>
</p>
```

Comment: I just found a variation on this approach to be helpful for multi-line `input type='text', wrapping the input, and then laying the text over it with a wrapper `div`.  That also requires `pointer-events:none;` on the `:before` in order to still be able to click the button below.

Answer (score 11):

To make an element have a line break afterwards, assign it:

`display:block;`

Non-floated elements after a block level element will appear on the next line. Many elements, such as <p> and <div> are already block level elements so you can just use those.

But while this is good to know, this really depends more on the context of your content. In your example, you would not want to use CSS to force a line break. The <br /> is appropriate because semantically the p tag is the the most appropriate for the text you are displaying. More markup just to hang CSS off it is unnecessary. Technically it's not *exactly* a paragraph, but there is no <greeting> tag, so use what you have. Describing your content well with HTMl is way more important - after you have that *then* figure out how to make it look pretty.

Comment: But this makes it the full width of the container, which might be an unwanted side effect (especially if the item is an anchor/link).

Comment: Yes, by default block level elements take up the full width unless you set a width. Read my paragraph about context - thinking in terms of semantic context rather than choosing your html based on your design generally helps prevent you from running into issues like that.

Comment: Often the reason <br> tags need to be avoided is more technical than semantic. <br> tags are standalone and you can't necessarily use them as you don't know if the elements in front will exist at the time you render the page, so you might not want blank lines. Consider a list of <a> links on a vertical menu where you want them all on their own line, but can't use <br> as you don't know which links will get hidden due to server-side rules. Hiding the links would cause blank lines if <br> were used.

Comment: ..For that reason, people often use a <ul> list and then hide the bullets, but that's pretty hacky. It would be better if there was a css rule which just said "always render on own line".

Comment: CSS does have a rule like that. It's called "display:block". BTW <li> are block level elements that's why they show on their own line. There is also the option of floating and clearing but personally I think that's messy if it's overused. The reason people use li and hide the bullets with css is actually a semantic one - if they are showing a list of items you should use a list item tag. Things get way less "hacky" when you put semantics first even if it seems technically harder - you actually end up with much easier code to work with.

Comment: But as I said in my first comment - that has the undesirable side effect of the elements being full width :)   I just need items on a new line, without them being full width. If the item is a link on the far left of the page, it means even clicks on the far right of the screen follow the link.

Comment: That's not "undesirable" it's just how CSS works and is why <a> tags are inline elements. This is off topic for this question and answer, but the way you deal with that is to either put an <a> tag inside a block level element for (just a text link) or explicitly set the width if you want it block level, (for example if you want to be able to click on a larger area including the padding) You could also set to inline-block and float and clear them as needed depending on what you're doing.

Answer (score 10):

```
<pre> <---------------------------------------
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
</pre> <--------------------------------------
```

OR

```
<div style="white-space:pre">  <-----------------------------------
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
</div>                         <-----------------------------------
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36191199/2377343

Answer (score 8):

Here's a bad solution to a bad question, but one that literally meets the brief:

```css
p {
    width : 12ex;
}

p:before {
    content: ".";
    float: right;
    padding-left: 6ex;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: typo or what should `ex` be? `p` and `e` are not that close on the keyboard, that's why I'm asking

Comment: @marczking - [the relative unit `ex` is defined as "Equal to the used x-height of the first available font."](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#ex-unit)

Comment: Bad or not, this is actually quite clever.

Answer (score 7):

Use `overflow-wrap: break-word;`  like:

```css
.yourelement{
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe someone will have the same issue as me:

I was in a element with `display: flex` so I had to use `flex-direction: column`.

Answer (score 5):

## For a List of Links

The other answers provide some good ways of adding line breaks, depending on the situation. But it should be noted that the `:after` selector is one of the better ways to do this for **CSS control over lists of links** (and similar things), for reasons noted below.

Here's an example, assuming a table of contents:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .toc a:after{ content: "\a"; white-space: pre; }
</style>

<span class="toc">
    <a href="#a1">Item A1</a> <a href="#a2">Item A2</a>
    <a href="#b1">Item B1</a> <a href="#b2">Item B2</a>
</span>
```

And here's Simon_Weaver's technique, which is simpler and more compatible. It doesn't separate style and content as much, requires more code, and there may be cases where you want to add breaks after the fact. Still a great solution though, especially for older IE.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .toc br{ display: none; } /* comment out for horizontal links */
</style>

<span class="toc">
    <a href="#a1">Item A1</a><br/> <a href="#a2">Item A2</a><br/>
    <a href="#b1">Item B1</a><br/> <a href="#b2">Item B2</a><br/>
</span>
```

Note the advantages of the above solutions:

- No matter the whitespace in the HTML, the output is the same (vs. `pre`)
- No extra padding is added to the elements (see NickG's `display:block` comments)
- You can easily switch between horizontal and vertical lists of links with some shared CSS without going into every HTML file for a style change
- No `float` or `clear` styles affecting surrounding content
- The style is separate from the content (vs. `<br/>`, or `pre` with hard-coded breaks)
- This can also work for loose links using `a.toc:after` and `<a class="toc">`
- You can add multiple breaks and even prefix/suffix text

Answer (score 5):

I like very simple solutions, here is one more:

```html
<p>hello <span>How are you</span></p>
```

and CSS:

```css
p {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Setting a `br` tag to `display: none` is helpful, but then you can end up with WordsRunTogether. I've found it more helpful to instead replace it with a space character, like so:

HTML:

```
<h1>
    Breaking<br />News:<br />BR<br />Considered<br />Harmful!
</h1>
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-device-width: 1281px){
    h1 br {content: ' ';}
    h1 br:after {content: ' ';}
}
```

Comment: You could also consider setting `br` to `display: inline-block; width: 1em;` which should prevent the words from running together when going horizontal.

Comment: I like your suggestion better. I’ll try that next time I encounter this.

Answer (score 3):

How about`<pre>` tag?

source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp

Comment: Oh! I see what you mean. Then you use whitespaces in your `<pre>` so it breaks the line. What if you want to have regular whitespaces?

Comment: The pre tag will interpret the carriage returns made within. So if you break your line between 'hello' and 'how are you' in a pre tag, the break will be render

Answer (score 3):

The code can be:

```html
<div class="text-class"><span>hello</span><span>How are you</span></div>
```

CSS would be:

```css
.text-class {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: In 2021, this should be the accepted the answer.  It's the least code and the least hacky.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a lot of padding and force text to be split to new line, for example

```css
p {
  padding-right: 50%;
}
```

Worked fine for me in a situation with responsive design, where only within a certain width range it was needed for text to be split.

Comment: Sounds a nice idea but increasing padding will also increase the overall width of an object. And that can have a negative effect, specially in the case of a responsive page.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the content within `<span class="class_name"></span>`. After it the line will be break.

`\A` means line feed character.

```
.class_name::after {
  content: "\A";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using** `white-space` **will not work** for long sentences without spaces like `HiHowAreYouHopeYouAreDoingGood...etc` to fix this consider using `word-wrap: break-word;` instead

it's made to allow long words to be able to break and wrap onto the next line., its used by **Facebook**, **Instagram** and **me**

**Example**

```css
#container {
    width: 40%;
    background-color: grey;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:10px;
}
#container p{
   white-space: pre-line;
    background-color: green;
}
.flex{
    display: flex;
}

#wrap {
    width: 30%;
    background-color: grey;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:10px;
}
#wrap p{
   word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<h1> white-space: pre-line;</h1>
<div class='flex'>

<div id="container">
<h5>With spaces </h5>
    <p>Sample Text 1 Sample Text 1 Sample Text 1 Sample Text 1 Sample Text 1 Sample Text 1 Sample Text 1</p>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <h5>No specaes (not working )</h5>  <p>HiHowAreYouHopeYouAreDoingGoodHiHowAreYouHopeYouAreDoingGoodHiHowAreYouHopeYouAreDoingGood</p>
</div>
</div>




<h1>  word-wrap: break-word;</h1>
<div class='flex'>

<div id="wrap">
<h5>With spaces </h5>
    <p>Sample Text 1 Sample Text 1 Sample Text 1 Sample Text 1 Sample Text 1 Sample Text 1 Sample Text 1</p>
</div>

<div id="wrap">
  <h5>No specaes (working )</h5>  <p>HiHowAreYouHopeYouAreDoingGoodHiHowAreYouHopeYouAreDoingGoodHiHowAreYouHopeYouAreDoingGoodHiHowAreYouHopeYouAreDoingGood</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

On [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/injecting-line-break/), `Chris Coyier` have tested lots of options and the final and pretty neat one was using `display:table`, Each one have their own problems which you will find out when you use `background-color` on the span!

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px 0 25px 0;
  text-align:center;
}
h1 span {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 900;
}

h1 span {
    background: black;
    padding: 1px 8px;
    display: table;
    margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="one">

  Break right after this
  <span>
    and before this
  </span>

</h1>
```

Here You can see all other options on `codepen`:

[Injecting a Line Break](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/LNamvy)

Answer (score 1):

A modern and simple solution could be setting the width like that:

`width: min-content;`

This CSS rule is mostly useful for text content, but not only:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-content

```css
p {
  margin: 20px;
  color: #222;
  font-family:'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
  border: 2px dotted grey;
  padding: 3px;
}

.max {
  width: max-content;
}

.min {
  width: min-content;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head />
  <body>
    <p class="max"> Max width available </p>
    <p class="min"> Min width available </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both Vincent Robert and Joey Adams answers are valid. If you don't want, however, change the markup, you can just insert a `<br />` using javascript.

There is no way to do it in CSS without changing the markup.

Comment: That's not accurate. One could use `:after` or `:before` to do that.

Comment: @ArturBodera It's not possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865937/using-before-and-after-css-selector-to-insert-html

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed an input button to have a line break before it.
I applied the following style to the button and it worked:

```
clear:both;
```

Comment: But it's not the case of answer. There is not floats in answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone...

You could do this:

```
<p>This is an <a class="on-new-line">inline link</a>?</p>
```

With this css:

```
a.on-new-line:before { 
  content: '&nbsp;'; 
  font-size:0; 
  display:block;
  line-height:0;
}
```

Comment: or ```.on-new-line:before {content: "";
        display: block;}```

Answer (score 0):

Using `&nbsp;` instead of spaces will prevent a break.

```
<span>I&nbsp;DONT&nbsp;WANT&nbsp;TO&nbsp;BREAK&nbsp;THIS&nbsp;LINE&nbsp;UP, but this text can be on any line.</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in Chrome:

```css
p::after {
  content: "-";
  color: transparent;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you did not want to use a breakpoint because it will always break the line. Is that correct? If so how about adding a breakpoint `<br />` in your text, then giving it a class like `<br class="hidebreak"/>` then using media query right above the size you want it to break to hide the `<br />` so it breaks at a specific width but stays inline above that width.

HTML:

```
<p>
The below line breaks at 766px.
</p>

<p>
 This is the line of text<br class="hidebreak"> I want to break.
</p>
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  br.hidebreak {display:none;}
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/517Design/o71yw5vd/

Comment: I just noticed that Simon_Weaver posted a answer similar to mine. Sorry Simon, wasn't trying to plagiarize your response. I didn't read all the answers before I posted mine and therefor did not notice yours. My bad... lesson learned.. I will read the other answers before posting mine in the future.

Comment: No worries! But you have to write me a poem. From https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp
`"Tip: The <br> tag is useful for writing addresses or poems."`

Answer (score 0):

**Simple easy solution.**
Name th **external paragraph class as 'parent'** and **internal paragraph as 'child'.**

**Set css property**

**parent**: *margin-bottom: 0;*

**child**: *margin-top: 0;*

**You are good to go.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Solve</title>
  <style>
    .parent {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    
    .child {
      margin-top: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p class="parent"> hello
    <p class="child">How are you</p>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```