# How to insert an external HTML in a div by CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying insert an external HTML template in a `<div>` by CSS but I can't. Firstly I tried with `content`, but I got no results.

```
.overbox {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;     
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    content: url("../mytemplate.html");     
    padding: 10px;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto; 
}
```

Any ideas? Maybe with jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: You can't use CSS to retrieve external content. You would definitely need to use JavaScript, or possibly a server-side include depending on where you're retrieving the content from.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, are you sure? This suggests otherwise https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

Comment: @AmmarCSE if you're referring to the URL you can provide to `content`, that only works reliably for images, not HTML.

Comment: **[This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5865996/3639582)** says `content` supports only text and not html. I would suggest jQuery `load()` here.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, but in the link I provided, the use an .html file as an example?

Answer (score 1):

CSS is meant for **adding presentation to the page**, **and not content**. Therefore I feel that you should use **JavaScript** if you want to **dynamically generate content**. CSS is not opt for this.

Reference: **[Link](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/content.html)**

Comment: Ok!! Now I know is not possible to add an html in "content"

Answer (score 1):

Does the content of the external template change depending on a users actions (ie an tick box is clicked or an option selected)?

Does the template need to be loaded multiple times into the same div (ie every few minutes or every time a button is clicked)?

If the answer to either of these questions is **yes** then you should be using ajax.  Something along the lines of the following would work:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '../mytemplate.html',
  success:function(data){
    $('.overbox').html(data);
  }
});
```

Please note that this is simplified and should also error check etc.  For more info see the [jquery docs on ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or '[The Perfect jQuery AJAX Request](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/the-perfect-jquery-ajax-request/)'.

If the answer to **both** the above questions is **no** then you should be using a server side language to include the file in the div before it is sent to the client.

An example of this using PHP would be:

```
<div class="overbox">
  <?php include '../mytemplate.html';?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary purpose of using the `content` in css is to insert static data `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements, what you trying to do is the task most suited for javascript. In content you can use url just to specify images but cannot render the complete html content.

Comment: He can't use external content but he can call local URI with content property not only images,

Comment: What do you mean with "local URI" exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I think that with javascript, jquery is the best way.
Try this function

```
   function addDiv() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'row';
     div.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="name" value="" />\
    <input type="text" name="value" value="" />\ 
    <input type="button" value="-" onclick="tempfunction()">';
     document.getElementById('content').appendChild(div);
   }
```

Comment: probably better to use ajax if loading an external html file

Comment: I see this function try to add a div, but exactly the aim is to insert an external html in a previously existing div

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have opted for this method, but `content` CSS property only works with Pseudo elements `before` and `after` . Your CSS code should be some thing like this.

```
.overbox:before{
content: url(../mytemplate.html);
position: absolute;     
background-color: #FFFFFF;
padding: 10px;
top: 25%;
left: 25%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
z-index:1002;
overflow: auto; 
 }
```

> Note: you can't use external link in content property.