# Title on :before element

Tags: css, sass, pseudo-element

Is there any way to have `title=""` attribute on `:before` element?

```
.h3{
   padding-right: 13px;
   &:before {
       font-size: 12px;
       z-index: 10;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865937/using-before-and-after-css-selector-to-insert-html

Comment: No. `::before` is a pseudo-element of CSS, isn't a HTML element, it hasn't attributes.