# How can I insert <span class="notifier">3</span> after <a> with CSS?

Tags: css-selectors

I want to add a notifier circle to one menu item on my WP site.
The styling is done in css and now it must be placed in a `<span>` tag that does not exist.
The `<span>` has to be placed after the `<a>` tag for it to work.
My approach is to use ::after but I can't seem to get the code to work.
What am I doing wrong?

I have tried many variations but no succes.

This does not work:

```
a::after { 
  content: "<span class="notifier">3</span>";
  }
.notifier {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.25rem;
    right: -0.5rem;
    background: #ea3326;
    width: 1.25rem;
    height: 1.25rem;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.225rem;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 100%;
    z-index: 97;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

The following also does not work. However it shows  the code `<span class="notifier">3</span>` on the front end but not the styling.

```
a::after { 
  content: "<span class=\"notifier\">3</span>";
  }
.notifier {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.25rem;
    right: -0.5rem;
    background: #ea3326;
    width: 1.25rem;
    height: 1.25rem;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.225rem;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 100%;
    z-index: 97;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I expect a red circle with a white 3 next to a button.

Answer (score 1):

[You can't inject HTML via pseudo elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865937/using-before-and-after-css-selector-to-insert-html), but you don't need to. Just make one style rule to insert the content and style as needed:

```css
a::after {
  content: "3";
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  background: #ea3326;
  width: 1.25rem;
  height: 1.25rem;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.25rem;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 100%;
  z-index: 97;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">foo</a>
```