# Can the ::after content of a pseudo element be a whole div? The ideia is to make a popover

Tags: html, css, angular, popover, pseudo-element

I am trying to make big popover when hovering a div, and the content of this popover is going to be another div. Is this possible using pseudo element?

Answer (score -1):

the ::after pseudo element will accept text but what about If you want to put HTML tags so you need jquery or js to to that
visit : [Using :before and :after CSS selector to insert Html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865937/using-before-and-after-css-selector-to-insert-html)

Answer (score -1):

Not with pure CSS. The `::after` pseudo-element is for simple text content and styling ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)).