# inlining / lambda function in pure css

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, less

I would like to be able to write `<div class="inlined">content</div>` or so, and have it transformed into some other html, using the content, and as defined by `inlined`. I would like to do this in pure CSS ie., no javascript.

For instance, that would be a function `inlined`:

```
<div data-descr="content"/> -> <div class="container"><div class="topright">content</div></div>
```

With some implementation "like":

```
div[data-descr] {
  content: <div class="container"><div class="topright">attr(data-descr)</div></div>;
}
```

If no pure CSS can be used, what would be a less/sass/js solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data attribute includes HTML, you can't use the `CSS` content property for this because your HTML will be treated as a string - it won't get parsed.

You should also avoid adding HTML to data attributes anyway.

You can do it with JavaScript, though, via [replaceWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith).

Try creating an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) for that markup you want to add. You can then reference that to get the HTML

```js
// helper function to handle new element creation
const createNewElement = content => {
  const container = document.createElement("div");
  container.classList.add("container");

  const inner = document.createElement("div");
  inner.classList.add("top-right");
  inner.innerHTML = dataObject[content];

  container.append(inner);

  return container;
}

// create an object to get the HTML for a specific describtion attribute
const dataObject = {
  content: `<div class="red">red text</div>`,
  content2: `<div class="green">green text</div>`,
  content3: `<div class="blue">blue text</div>`,
}

// get the elements you want to change
const targetElements = document.querySelectorAll("[data-descr]");

// loop through them and swap them
targetElements.forEach(element => {
  const content = element.dataset.descr;
  const newElement = createNewElement(content)
  element.replaceWith(newElement)
})
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}

.blue {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<div data-descr="content"></div>
<div data-descr="content2"></div>
<div data-descr="content3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @ErikMartino in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5865996/8106583

> content doesn't support HTML, only text. You should probably use
> javascript, jQuery or something like that.

> If content did support HTML you could end up in an infinite loop where
> content is added inside content.