# How to add Mui Icon to the Content of pseudo elements (::after,::before) in React?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use mui Icons with pseudo Element "::before" with SX

here is my code:

```
import ArrowLeftIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ArrowLeft";

sx={{
                "&.Mui-selected::before": {
                  content: '"ArrowLeftIcon"',
                },
```

How to  add ArrowLeftIcon to the content

Comment: Following document will help you to resolve your issue: 
https://smartdevpreneur.com/styling-material-ui-before-after-hover-active/

Comment: @Akshayphalphale thank you for your response... I've checked the link and  it's not related to the problem... I have no problem with styling pseudo Element ... my problem is how to add mui icon to that pseudo element content

Comment: Is it mandatory to use icons from `@mui/icons-material` package or is it ok if you use icons directly from [Material Icons](https://fonts.google.com/icons?icon.set=Material+Icons)?

Comment: @AhmetEmreKılınç with Material Icons I jsut add The code point to the content ,right?

Answer (score 2):

Since [`content` does not support HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5865996/7399478), you need to get the HTML content of the svg icon using `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup` and then convert it to a data URL like this:

import ReactDOMServer :

```
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
```

need a state variable for data URL:

```
const [muiIconContent, setMuiIconContent] = React.useState();
```

convert svg component to data URL:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const iconSvg = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<ArrowLeftIcon />);
    const svgIconWithXlmns = iconSvg.replace(
      "<svg ",
      '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" '
    );
    const resultUrl = "url('data:image/svg+xml," + svgIconWithXlmns + "')";
    setMuiIconContent(resultUrl);
}, []);
```

add data URL to style:

```
sx={{
     "&.Mui-selected::before": {
      content: muiIconContent,
      width: 30
    }
}}
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-icon-before-forked-091w6l?file=/demo.tsx:1159-1493) for a live working example of this approach.