# Inline <div> column elements with pure CSS

Tags: html, css, dom

I have a table-like structure where the columns represent the logical entities. For my use case, it's the table *rows* that need to be visually grouped, preferably by flowing them inline.

Example source fragment:

```
<div>
  <div id="entity1" class="entities">
    <div>Ab</div>
    <div>Cdefg</div>
  </div>
  <div id="entity2" class="entities">
    <div>98224</div>
    <div>511</div>
  </div>
  <div id="entity3" class="entities">
    <div>αβγδ</div>
    <div>ε</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Desired layout:

```
+----+-------+------+
| Ab | 98224 | αβγδ |
+----+--+----++---+-+
| Cdefg | 511 | ε |
+-------+-----+---+
```

Of course, it is easy to transform the document on the server-side purely for the presentation, but I wonder if I can keep the document hierarchy as it is and do the transformation on the (CSS) presentation layer. Is it at all possible?

Comment: adding php to the script will work better, that's my opnion. you can use looping there with in loop you will be able to apply CSS rules..that's an idea man..

Comment: Well, you can already get quite close with this CSS fragment: `.entities { display: inline-block; }`. The question is if it's actually possible to make the "rows" flow inline as shown in the example.

Comment: No clue why this would have 2 downvotes. It seems pretty clear to me, and if the downvotes came previously, the question didn't seem that bad when it was first asked either.

Comment: The OP's issue is quite considerable as an effective design issue. Deserve my upvote.

Comment: Assuming you wanted a super quick fix..you *could* duplicate your markup (not recommended though) like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/jWRTD/) (I had to change ids as well)

Comment: @glts i can understand how it feels to get two +1s and two -1s... I respect your curiosity though.. +1 to your question.. meanwhile check my answer

Comment: @Danield: That seems to be the basis for how CSS regions work, based on my less-than-familiar understanding of the module (except of course it doesn't involve duplicating of content).

Comment: Not possible with CSS only.  But if you don't want to touch the source code, you could consider transforming via JS, to do something like @Danield did.

Comment: Is your content always going to be one-line single word text in the `.entities div` elements?

Comment: @MarcAudet Not sure if I understand. The structure is completely regular. Every `div.entities` contains exactly the same number of child divs. But the leaves don't necessarily contain just a single word, `<div>ε</div>` could also be `<div>εζ ηθι</div>`.

Comment: have you tried `display:table` with the parents and the table-row with children? if you have and it didn't work, then I will start working on other solutions, just just wanted clarification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in your comment and in the other answers, it's trivial to lay entire `.entities` elements as inline blocks or to float them in order to line up their contents in rows, resembling a proper table. (Ironically, you *can't* replicate this layout using [CSS2.1 table properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html).)

However, if you need to lay each content element inline such that each row does not act like a table row rather than simply a *line* of boxes, as shown in your diagram, it's not possible with your given structure due to the way inline formatting works in CSS. Restructuring your content to accommodate such a layout is as simple as arranging the content by row and not by column, which I'm sure you have covered so I won't get into that.

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-boxes):

> *Inline-level elements* are those elements of the source document that do not form new blocks of content; the content is distributed in lines (e.g., emphasized pieces of text within a paragraph, inline images, etc.). The following values of the 'display' property make an element inline-level: 'inline', 'inline-table', and 'inline-block'. Inline-level elements generate *inline-level boxes*, which are boxes that participate in an inline formatting context.

An [inline formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-formatting) can typically only be generated by a [block container box](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-boxes):

> A *block container box* either contains only block-level boxes or establishes an inline formatting context and thus contains only inline-level boxes.

In your structure, the only possible block container boxes are generated by each `div`. So the first `.entities` contains its own two children, and likewise for the second and third for their own children. You cannot transfer child elements across different containing blocks that are siblings, therefore you cannot distribute children of different elements across the same line, even if you force all of them to `display: inline` or if you force the content elements to `display: inline-block`.

Note that the top-level `div` element creates an inline formatting context as well but it cannot be used by your inner elements in this manner for the same reason.

Also, to address this part of your bounty statement:

> CSS does have quite a few devices that alter the flow and alignment of boxes.

Unfortunately, this isn't possible even with [flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox), as flex containers work similarly to block containers and are therefore subject to the same limitations described above with respect to inline-level descendants.

This *may* be doable to a certain extent with [CSS regions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-regions), but I'm not familiar with that module, and there's too little support for it to be relevant at this time anyway (even compared to flexbox).

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
.entities{
display:inline-block;
}
```

but this gives the following format:

```
+-------+-------+------+
| Ab    | 98224 | αβγδ |
+-------+-------+------+
| Cdefg | 511   | ε    |   
+-------+-------+---+--+
```

if you want the format you desire, then you might want to change your HTML code up a bit:

```
    <div>
  <div id="entity1" class="entities">
    <span class="cell">Ab</span>        
    <span class="cell">98224</span>
    <span class="cell">αβγδ</span>
  </div>
  <div id="entity2" class="entities">
    <span class="cell">Cdefg</span>
    <span class="cell">511</span>
    <span class="cell">ε</span>
  </div>
  <div id="entity3" class="entities"> 
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cell{
display:inline-block;
}
```

this gives the following layout:

```
+----+-------+------+
| Ab | 98224 | αβγδ |
+----+--+----++---+-+
| Cdefg | 511 | ε |
+-------+-----+---+
```

well, if you want to use the exact same HTML as you provided then, the answer is **no**...

the exact one you wanted, hope it helped!

Comment: Please do not post as "answer" something already posted by another person as a comment. Sometimes this is unavoidable such as when you begin your post before the comment was posted or without having a reasonable amount of time to see that comment -- but in this case, I'm sure you'll agree that the 20 month time gap gave you plenty of time, no?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @mah here's my research: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-css-div-width-equal-to-contents http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703601/how-to-give-line-break-from-css-without-using-br/2703615#2703615

Comment: Anshuman read the comments under the question -- the one from @glts : `Well, you can already get quite close with this CSS fragment: .entities { display: inline-block; }. The question is if it's actually possible to make the "rows" flow inline as shown in the example.`. Now that you've extended your answer it's certainly improved -- much beyond what you originally posted; thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`<div>`s are boxes, so I'm not sure that you'll be able to get the alignment you're looking for without styling each cell `<div>` individually. The closest I can approximate what you want is by attaching `class="heading"` to the entity `<div>`s:

HTML:

```
  <div id="entity1" class="heading">
    <div>Ab</div>
    <div>Cdefg</div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
div.heading {float: left;}
div.heading div {display: block; padding-right: 15px;}
```

but this just makes a table out of `<div>` elements.

If you are creating a table-like structure, why not use a `<table>`? Unless the misaligned column borders are essential, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Give 'cells' class names, along with the 'rows'

```
<div>
  <div class="row" id="entity1">
    <div class="cell1">Ab</div>
    <div class="cell2">Cdefg</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {position:relative;}
.cell1 {width:33%;}
.cell2 {width:66%;}
```

This should work, so long as you have a general idea of the width needed for each column.

Answer (score 1):

Mayby `:nth-child()` with `clear:left` can help you

```
.container div:nth-child(4n){clear:left;}
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/rhbRK/)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm not answering the css-question directly, but I wanna widen the perspective on the use of html-structure. *(can't post comments)*

***I'm slightly puzzled*** *by what you are trying to present with that kind of data and that html structure, especially if you have bigger datasets.* Because PHP+/SQL would do you so much good in this case, as stated in a comment above.

I'm quessing that you are trying to represent *relations between the entities*, 1 relation on each row. But I'd say you've structured your html in a rather peculiar way for that purpose.

I've done some research regarding issues on the stucture that your html-code have, and I made a fiddle to show you what I mean: `"Relation-rows by entity-columns"`

The html structure I propose is the one [Anshuman suggested above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19476553/2808954). I've recreated the structure he mentioned  but done it so in a more pragmatic fashion. I've also evaluated the potential problems but also why this structure would suit the purpose better. (Atleast the purpose that I've percepted from your dataset.) Take a look at it here: 
`"Relation-rows by entity-rows"`

Answer (score 0):

Hi please flow blew code, I thing solve your problem

```
.entities{
display: inline;
float: left;
position: relative;
clear: right;
```

}