# Equivalent of <br> tag

Tags: html, internet-explorer, tags, cross-browser

in Internet Explorer 5.5,6 & 7, the `<br>` tag takes one more space.

I am working on dynamic hide/show row of table. I met an issue while hiding a row, the row next to it having `<br>` in their data (*Regard as rabid unless proven `<br>` negative by laboratory* ), takes more space.

Is it possible to achieve the same functionality of `<br>` with `<div>` or `<p>` tag?

Comment: It is a bit hard to understand your question. could you add an html snippet to show what you mean? (just prepend the text with four spaces and the html will show)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you just want to make a `<br />` with CSS.
This question is already answered:

[How to give line-break from css, without using <br />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703601/how-to-give-line-break-from-css-without-using-br)

Comment: you just want to make a ...? with CSS

Comment: @Mark tenhouse wrote <br /> in question source, and it has been converted to a line break. To avoid that you just need to use code formatting. If you find such strange behaviour look at the source of the question / answer by clicking the edit link and you'll probably find the cause.

Comment: @Gabber i know, i was giving himself the opportunity to fix it, without me having to edit 1 or 3 chars where the minimum is 6.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this if your still wondering:

```
<style>
p {
white-space: pre;
}
</style>
<p>hello
How are you</p>
```

This doesn't work in IE6 or 7 i have no idea about 8

```
p span {
    Border: pre;
}
<p><span>hello my name is</span>Thomas</p>
```

the above is another way of doing it. it should work in all browsers

Answer (score -1):

From a semantic point of view, no. `<p>` and `<div>` are tags enclosing text. But of cource, you may use `<p>`'s or `<div>`'s to achieve something that looks like what the `<br>` is doing (*although you probably need some CSS to make it look exactly the same way*).

Comment: MortenSickel: wat you are saying doesn't make any sense.