# Add line breaks to Literal controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have some problems with the ASP.NET `Literal` control because it isn't rendering the `<br/>` tag.

code

```
string strTemp = task.Description.ToString();
lit_description.Text = strTemp.Replace("\r\n", "<br/>");
```

output:

```
LG SERVICE TICKET<br/><br/> <br/><br/>- DATE IN (eg. Feb 11, 2011):<br/><br/>- DATE OUT (eg. Feb 11, 2011):<br/><br/>- Client Has Critical Data (fees will apply):<br/><br/>- Windows Password: <br/><br/>- Accessories:<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>Client Complaint:<br/><br/><br/><br/>
```

Comment: Why you dont try use spans that you will then display as blocks. <p><span>LG SERVICE TICKET</span><span>DATE</span></p> 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703601/how-to-give-line-break-from-css-without-using-br

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set it's [`Mode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode.aspx) to `PassThrough`:

```
<asp:Literal Id="lit_description" Mode="PassThrough"></asp:Literal>
```

> **PassThrough** The contents of the control are not modified.

Comment: you are Great Tim. A Big Salute to you :)