# Limit Radio Buttons displayed per line

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

I have a list being returned from a database that can potentially be a different size each time.   The list is loaded onto a html page `<div id="availableTimes"></div>` using

```
$.each(returnData.availableTimes, function (index, value) {                        
     $("#availableTimes").append('<input type=radio name=availableTimes value= ' 
        + value.id + '>' + '<label id=' + value.id + '>' + value.time + '</label>');
});
```

What I would like to be able to do is limit the amount of radio buttons and labels displayed per line to 4.  Is there a value I can set in CSS or do I have to insert a `<br />` every 4 records in the JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without floats, you can add line break on the label

```
#availableTimes label:nth-child():after {
    content:"\a";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8FALp/1/

Answer (score 4):

You could use nth-child selectors to clear every 5th element (that has been floated). Really, you can break the line however you want, just use the nth-child selector to do so...

Like so:

```
#availableTimes input {
    float:left;
}

#availableTimes input:nth-child(4n + 1) {
    clear:left;
}
```

EDIT: use (4n + 1) rather than (5n)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you're going to need to put a `<br>` tag every four records. AFAIK, there's no way to create a line-break using just CSS. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703601/how-to-give-line-break-from-css-without-using-br) has a few more solutions, if you want to look into those