# How to present user text with new lines inside a div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, newline

I have a [bootstrap panel](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels-basic) that contains text that was previously inserted by the user. 
The user text may contain new lines.

What's the best way do display those new lines? I've found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2703609/4398050) and it works if I put a `<p>` element inside the `div`. Another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2703610/4398050) seems impossible since it would require text replacing, that may be problematic.

Is this the best approach? Will it work on major browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution was:

`<p style="white-space: pre">user-text</p>`

it seems to be working correctly

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try use `<pre>` HTML-tag. In this case new-lines will be displayed as is

Answer (score 0):

jQuery solution that might work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.each($('.panel-body'), function(k, panel_body) {
    $(panel_body).html($(panel_body).text().replace(new RegExp('\r?\n','g'), '<br />'));
  });
});
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid text replacement, cause I'm pretty sure that some edge case will be broken with such approach