# End of the lines and tabs in html

Tags: html

I receive non-HTML text from the user and store it in a database.
My database stores text with '\n' characters for end of the line.

```
- list one text\n
- list 2 text\n
```

This can be see in the browser source code, but isn't reflected in the rendered HTML. How can I fix this?

Comment: i think you can just change \n with <br> tag

Comment: `\n` - is UNIX-style line ending for line break. Are you using a server-side language at all (HTML on its own can't fix this issue - someone correct me if I'm wrong :))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Line break in html with \`\n\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325414/line-break-in-html-with-n)

Comment: If its a database you must be getting it with some other language - what is it? As probably you can change it after fetching the data before sending to the html. Otherwise onload you can use JS/jQuery to go and find each `\n` and swap it for `<br/>`

Comment: I use python as backend, I thought maybe are some special characters/encoding like non-braking space

Comment: in that case... pos duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369159/replace-n-with-br

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the correct way to display multi line text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49719774/whats-the-correct-way-to-display-multi-line-text)