# Create new line or line break using CSS

Tags: css

I have a a bunch of radio button & labels as following:

```
<input type="radio" id="FID3626" name="Discipline" value="Yes" class="" title="" data-test="test">
<label for="">Yes </label>

<input type="radio" id="FID3626" name="Discipline" value="No" class="" title="" data-test="test">
<label for="">No </label>

<input type="radio" id="FID3626" name="Discipline" value="May be" class="" title="" data-test="test">
<label for="">May be </label>

<input type="radio" id="FID3626" name="Discipline" value="Option A" class="" title="" data-test="test">
<label for="">Option A </label>

<input type="radio" id="FID3626" name="Discipline" value="Option B" class="" title="" data-test="test">
<label for="">Option B </label>

<input type="radio" id="FID3626" name="Discipline" value="Option C" class="" title="" data-test="test">
<label for="">Option C </label>

<input type="radio" id="FID3626" name="Discipline" value="Option D" class="" title="" data-test="test">
<label for="">Option D </label>

<input type="radio" id="FID3626" name="Discipline" value="Option E" class="" title="" data-test="test">
<label for="">Option E </label>
```

And these are generated from metadata. After rendering, these appear in one line, which is normal.

I need each of the label & its radio in one line. I need to this using CSS. For some reason i cannot keep the input & label under one div.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: means you cant use tag like <div> or <p>..right?

Comment: Do you have a parent element a DIV?

Comment: You can use css property of `display:block;`
[See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703601/how-to-give-line-break-from-css-without-using-br)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the pseudo element `::after`. Check below example.

```css
label::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="FID3626" name="Discipline" value="Yes" class="" title="" data-test="test">
<label for="">Yes</label>

<input type="radio" id="FID3626" name="Discipline" value="No" class="" title="" data-test="test">
<label for="">No</label>

<input type="radio" id="FID3626" name="Discipline" value="May be" class="" title="" data-test="test">
<label for="">May be</label>

<input type="radio" id="FID3626" name="Discipline" value="Option A" class="" title="" data-test="test">
<label for="">Option A</label>

<input type="radio" id="FID3626" name="Discipline" value="Option B" class="" title="" data-test="test">
<label for="">Option B</label>

<input type="radio" id="FID3626" name="Discipline" value="Option C" class="" title="" data-test="test">
<label for="">Option C</label>

<input type="radio" id="FID3626" name="Discipline" value="Option D" class="" title="" data-test="test">
<label for="">Option D</label>

<input type="radio" id="FID3626" name="Discipline" value="Option E" class="" title="" data-test="test">
<label for="">Option E</label>
```

Comment: Great...Nice one. :)

Answer (score -1):

here you go

```css
label { display: block; }
```

```html
<label for="">Yes
  <input type="radio" id="FID3626" name="Discipline" value="Yes" class="" title="" data-test="test">
</label>

<label for="">No
  <input type="radio" id="FID3626" name="Discipline" value="No" class="" title="" data-test="test">
</label>
```