# How to break a line after some certain width in css

Tags: html, css

I am designing a chat ui.

In my chat bubble when i enter a lot of characters it goes outside the bubble.

Are there any css techniques to break a line after certain width ?

Comment: Try this. `word-break:break-word` hope this one helps

Comment: i think you can use word wrap

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give line-break from css, without using <br />?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703601/how-to-give-line-break-from-css-without-using-br)

Comment: Give window a specific width and use word-break:break-all;

Comment: Thanx for ur helps .. Problem fixed :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
.your-bubble {
    width: 250px; // width can be depend on you
    white-space: normal;
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

May this will help your problem

Answer (score 1):

```css
p{
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #111;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<p>some random text jfkdfjkd jkfdkf</p>
```

Comment: If I'm designing a chat ui I would not use break-all.

Comment: I'm agree with @Ryad.iv, this wouldn't efective for chat apps

Comment: @IamNOOB Have you tried some text like : "HELLO I'M A REALLY LONG TEXT BLABLA BLABLABLA AND BLABLABLA, PLEASE TRY ME TO YOUR CHATTING BUBBLE WKAKA" ? And you see seperated words there

Comment: Oh i did not try it. WHat will be the solution for it then ? :(

Comment: Use break-word; instead of break-all;

Comment: @Ryad.iv Maybe he like to make some fun with the user wkwkwk i think the user will be annoyed if the normal text was seperated