# Create Line breaks with css using spans

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an `h1` tag with each word wrapped in a span with a class such as `word1 word2` etc.

I need to wrap these words in a specific order.

The sentence is `"software designed to make life easier."`

I need this to be broken up so it is formatted as such:

```
software
designed
to make
life easier.
```

I do not have the ability to change the h1 to include line breaks so I am having to wrap each word with a span using jQuery.

```html
<h1 class="et_pb_module_header">
  <span class="word1">software</span> <span class="word2" style="">designed</span> <span class="word3">to</span> <span class="word4" style="">make</span> <span class="word5" style="">life</span> <span class="word6">easier.</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give line-break from css, without using <br />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703601/how-to-give-line-break-from-css-without-using-br)

Comment: `display: block` ...?

Comment: spans are inline elements and don't naturally break the line. So you'd have to set them to be block-level (as Rory suggested and is given as the solution in the duplicate posted by Carsten), or use `<br/>` instead of `<span>` . If you don't understand about inline vs block-level, and which elements default to which display type then please research the "display" CSS property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create the effect with the `:after` or `::after` pseudo element. It's not a clean solution, but I can't think of a cleaner one.

```css
.word1:after,
.word2:after,
.word4:after,
.word6:after {
content: "";
display: block;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="et_pb_module_header">
  <span class="word1">software</span> <span class="word2" style="">designed</span> <span class="word3">to</span> <span class="word4" style="">make</span> <span class="word5" style="">life</span> <span class="word6">easier.</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: `display:block` is cleaner

Comment: It would be if each span was being added on a separate line. The last two lines include 2 spans per line and the `content` is required for the pseudo elements.

Comment: But i think need to break all `spans` like this `h1.et_pb_module_header span {
    display: block;
}`

Comment: Display:block would work and is used on other parts of the site but I am not breaking after every word so it isn't suitable in this case. The pseudo method should work better as I am not breaking every span