# Replace \n with <br/> in C#

Tags: c#, html

I have a problem with converting \n to < br/>. 
The text I want to convert is `test\ntest\n\ntest`
I want it to be like `test<br />test<br /><br />test`.
So every \n needs to be replaced with `<br />`.

Now I'm using this code:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\n)+");
string ticketCategorieOmschrijving = regex.Replace("test\ntest\n\ntest", "<br />");
```

But this code replaces `\n\n` to a single `<br />`, while it needs to be `<br /><br />`

Can someone help?

Comment: Why go the Regex route when you can just use [String.Replace()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_)?
`"test\ntest\n\ntest".Replace("\n", "<br/>");`

Comment: I'd suggest using CSS to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2703609/34092 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use String `Replace` method:

```
str = str.Replace("\n", "<br />");
```