# Oracle Apex SQL Workshop - New line(CHR10) not working in varchar DB column

Tags: oracle-apex

I need to display text with line breaks in email.
The source database column has datatype varchar2(1000).

However in sql workshop, when i update it using CHR(10), it does not introduce line breaks and the output comes in single line. Even in application/email body, its showing as single line.

```
update text set text_content='Life' 
||CHR(10)
||CHR(10)
'The very essence';
```

The output is simply: Life The very essence.

Instead of:
Life

The very essence.

How can i introduce line breaks?

Apex version : 20.1

Comment: emails are usually sent in html - it's safer to user ```<br>``` to display line breaks

Comment: i need to save the text in db table and fetch from there. So basically in db i need to push it with line breaks. And there neither chr(10), nor <br/> is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Workshop is not a good way to determine the line break is there. It is an invisible character and in SQL Workshop you can't see it.
Run the following code

```
WITH mydata (c)
AS 
(
    SELECT 'Hello'||chr(10)||'world' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT 
  c,
  REPLACE(c,chr(10),'X')
  FROM mydata;
```

That shows that the line break is there.
To make it visible in email, the best way is to replace the chr(10) with a `<br>` tag since email is usually sent in html. You can also use css classes as explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703601/how-to-line-break-from-css-without-using-br)

Comment: If the text in html is directly coming from database column how can we format it using br tag if its dynamic?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "how can we format it using br tag if its dynamic". What is "its" in that sentence ? Have you tried ```REPLACE(text,chr(10),'<br>')```. Please describe exactly what you are trying and what fails