# How to convert newline \n to line break <br> on Oracle APEX Reports

Tags: oracle, report, oracle-apex

Usually developers will have issues on adding line breaks to apex reports. Specially when working with content rows.

[example of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09Oup.png)

Here is a quick fix.

1. Find the content row selector for the report region. In my case class="t-ContentRow-description"
2. Add javascript to replace \n to 
    at the page load
   [Adding Javascript to Page Load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rG4Oe.png)

`let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.t-ContentRow-description'); elements.forEach(function(element) { // Replace newline characters with <br> let updatedContent = element.textContent.replace(/\n/g, '<br><br>'); element.innerHTML = updatedContent; });`

[after the fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XobUn.png)

Thank me later :-)

By default apex won't allow to render html tags on report regions so pl/sql codes like `REPLACE(REPLACE(OUTCOMES, CHR(13)||CHR(10), '<br/>'), CHR(10), '<br/>')`  won't work and it will cause to display 
 than adding a line break

Comment: Please [edit] the question so that it asks a question and delete the solution from the question; then you can post your solution into an answer to that question. Self-answers to questions are allowed (and encouraged) but including answers in the question is not allowed (StackOverflow is a question-and-answer site where questions and answers are separate, it is not a forum or a blog).

Comment: referencing a selector might not be upgrade proof. There are more solid alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

> Thank me later :-)

Later is now, so - thank you.

---

I created test table with two columns, `ID` and `TEXT`, where text stored in that column looks like this:

```
* Architect prod & non-prod environment app & db deployment architecture
* Architect & design
* Review source and target
```

By default, if you don't do anything, output (in a **classic report**; you didn't specify *which* report your developers used) looks as your screenshot shows - everything goes into the same line:

```
* Architect prod & non-prod environment app & db deployment architecture * Architect & design * Review source and target
```

Query which replaces CRLF with `<br>` tags:

```
select ID,
   replace(replace(TEXT, chr(10), '<br>'), chr(13), '<br>') text
from TEST
```

Output won't change, unless you navigate to `TEXT` column's properties and switch the **Escape special characters** property **OFF**. Run the report again, and output is OK:

[image]

Switch to **interactive report**; with the same property turned OFF:

[image]

---

Therefore, yes - thank you for sharing, but there's a simpler way to do that. Send link to this *question* (answer, actually) to your developers, maybe they'll find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

Just as an overview, here are a couple of options to render line breaks in reports (feel free to add):

Source Query:

```
select NOTE_ID,
       NOTE_TEXT
  from IG_NOTES
```

##### Classic Report

- **HTML Expression attribute of the column**

```
<span style="white-space:pre-wrap; width:100%; word-wrap:break-word;">#NOTE_TEXT#</span>
```

- **css class**

Define css class inline in page or in a file

```
.wrapped-text {
  white-space:pre-wrap; 
  width:100%; 
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

More about line breaks in css [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703601/how-to-line-break-from-css-without-using-br)

Then add the css class in the column attribute

[image]

- **replace in sql and escape special characters**

See @Littlefoot answer

##### Interactive Report

- **HTML Expression attribute of the column (same as classic)**

```
<span style="white-space:pre-wrap; width:100%; word-wrap:break-word;">#NOTE_TEXT#</span>
```

- **css class**

css class cannot be assigned to a column, but it can be referenced in an html expression.

```
<span class="wrapped-text">#NOTE_TEXT#</span>
```

- **replace in sql and escape special characters**

See @Littlefoot answer

##### Interactive Grid

- **css class**

Use **Column Initialization Javascript Function** for the column

```
function(config) {     
    config.defaultGridColumnOptions = {         
        cellTemplate: '<span style="white-space:pre-wrap; width:100%; word-wrap:break-word;">&NOTE_TEXT.</span>'     
    };     
    return config; 
}
```

- **replace in sql and escape special characters**

Since there is no "escape special characters" in an IG, the **Column Initialization Javascript Function** is needed:

```
function(config) {     
    config.defaultGridColumnOptions = {         
        cellTemplate: '<pre>&NOTE_TEXT.</pre>'     
    };     
    return config; 
}
```